# How could this character have been teleported while the Enterprise's shields were up?

Tags: star-trek, teleportation, star-trek-into-darkness

During the attack by the USS Vengeance,

> Carol Marcus

insists on talking to the Vengeance's captain,

> Admiral Marcus, her father.

Shortly afterward he stops his attack and beams this character off the Enterprise onto the Vengeance.

Wasn't the Enterprise under attack just a minute before that? That would mean that the Enterprise had her shields up, something that we know [blocks transporter beams](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8733/why-cant-transport-be-initialized-when-shields-are-up). **How was he able to beam them up while the Enterprise' had her shields up?**

Comment: I just watched this and I am fairly certain that they make it clear that their shields were down at that point.

Comment: @NominSim This question was inspired by [this review](http://www.filmschoolrejects.com/opinions/why-star-trek-into-darkness-works-despite-its-many-flaws.php) and I was not able to tell why he was bale to do so : Quote from the review (SPOILERS): *"There are other, smaller nitpicks, [...] and how Marcus is able to beam Carol from the Enterprise to his ship despite the fact that the Enterprise HAD to have their shields up since they were just being fired upon "*. I was not able to remember they stated the shield were down.

Comment: I am almost 100% certain that I remember them specifically say that their shields had failed...I'm not sure what the reviewer means by they "HAD to have their shields up since they were just being fired upon". It isn't a requirement that shields are up to be fired upon, and the reason that they were taking so much damage was due to the fact that their shields were down.

Comment: Yeah the next shot was a kill shot. Shields were dead.

Comment: A lot of this question isn't especially spoilerish (unless you think ***"[The Enterprise engages in life-or-death space battle with another ship](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StandardStarshipScuffle)"*** is a spoiler) and I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There were no shields available during the transport. The last volley tore a hole in the hull of the Enterprise on the engineering deck and depleted the last of her shield power. The fact that Enterprise could no longer prevent damage to her hull implies her shield power is gone.

Note the resignation of the crew as the transport takes place. There isn't anything anyone can do to stop it.

When the Enterprise entertains the idea of another act of resistance, the shield strength is measured at 6%. Not even sufficient to resist one more volley of anything.

Comment: This confuses me. Because after Khan takes control of Marcus' ship, he tells Spock he wants to trade Kirk for his crew. Spock says that he has no transporter capabilities, and then Khan states that his are perfectly functional and orders Spock to drop shields. Spock orders Sulu to lower shields, and then when the Enterprise is falling to Earth, Sulu says that they will burn up upon re-entry if they can't get power and shields back online. Maybe it's just something that the continuity team missed?

Comment: @Stephanie: Shields can be repaired/recharged as well as be damaged/taken down. That's why starships have engineering crews aboard.

Comment: @user17489: Continuity team?  For post-2009 Star Trek??  Haha.  Sure.

Answer (score 2):

### Shield were down at that point.

> **KIRK:** *Damage report!*
>
> **SULU:** *Weapons are way down. **Shields are dropping.***
>
> [a second later]
>
> **DARWIN:** ***We're defenceless,*** sir.
>
> <sub><sup>[Into Darkness Transcript - Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/Extras/STintoD.html)</sup></sub>

A slightly different version of the exchange appears in the film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_(novel)), presumably based on an earlier version of the script.

> *Another blast rocked the artificial gravity on the bridge. If they lost that, Kirk knew, they would be almost helpless. “Evasive maneuvers! Get us to Earth now! Full impulse! Once we cross the halfway point between home and the moon, we can—”
>
>   **“Shields are gone, Captain,”** Sulu broke in. “Impulse power failing! We’re losing the last of our powered forward momentum.”*
>
> ...
>
> *Her eyes widened as the import of her father’s words struck home. As an all-too-familiar set of lights began to swarm her, she turned helplessly toward Kirk.
>
>   **“Can we intercept their transport signal?” he called out.
>
>   “No, sir!” a tech quickly responded.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek Into Darkness - Official Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness_(novel))</sup></sub>